# Differential equation simplification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In some math model tutorial faced with such cosequence of statements. Can't remember how to find simplification in math diff equations. Could someone help, how the second statement has been simplified to the third? Why  we could consider dx and dy as const?

[image]

Comment: Rather than linking or posting a picture, please type your equations up in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This step is done by integrating (this is usually what we do when we separate the $\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm dy$ as shown).$$ax\,\mathrm dx=by\,\mathrm dy\implies \int ax\,\mathrm dx=\int by\,\mathrm dy\\\implies \frac12a x^2+C_1=\frac12by^2+C_2\\\implies ax^2-by^2=2(C_2-C_1)=\text{constant}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!..